# PHP, Python processing or MySQL processing on a large date set?

Tags: php, python, mysql

I have 2 million rows in a myqsl DB which have multiple columns of contacts as phone_1, phone_2 upto phone_10.
These phone no. may or may not duplicate.
I intend to group them together..as

```
ID  Contact_1  Contact_2  Contact_3  
P1      1          2           3 
P2      5          6           7
P3      2          8           9
```

result should be:

```
ID  Contact_1  Contact_2  Contact_3  Group
P1      1          2           3       1
P2      5          6           7       2
P3      2          8           9       1
P3      11         12          13      3
P3      7          21          22      2
```

Now where should I do the processing part ...PHP/Python or mysql.
i.e. select the entire data in php script and create an arrray and process tha array and then use insert query.

OR
select the entire data in php script and then use UPDATE(with a logic to create groups) query.
??
I have group field in DB table.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, I'd say mostly on how comfortable you are with each language. I would probably do this with PHP, but that's the language I know best.

You can certainly do it purely with MySql, and the operation would probably run faster, but it might be easier to debug and test each step in PHP or Python.

Regardless, I'd recommend first creating a data subset, maybe 1000 or 2000 rows from the table and running everything against that until you're happy with the results. It'll be much much faster and you'll see mistakes sooner.

Also, I'd avoid running anything you're worried about being slow on a production server.